# AngularJS - Ignore parent route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The parent route doesn't contain any view. I put the child routes in a parent to share its name so that the url becomes like this `.../sites/site1` or `.../sites/site2`

```
$stateProvider
    .state('sites', {
        url: '/sites',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('sites.site1', {
        url: '/site1',
        templateUrl: 'templates/site1.html'
    })
    .state('sites.site2', {
        url: '/site2',
        templateUrl: 'templates/site2.html'
    })
    // ...
    // Other routes
```

But this doesn't seem to work when I go to :

```
<a ui-sref="sites.site1">Go to first site</a>
<a ui-sref="sites.site2">Go to second site</a>
```

Nothing's showing up. (Other normal routes are working fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a target in parent for a child:

```
.state('sites', {
    url: '/sites',
    abstract: true,
    // THIS line is essential, 
    // 1) it will inject the parent template into root 
    //    (index.html) ui-view=""
    // 2) and will also create a target for a child view
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
})
```

The reason is: child state is using implicit view naming, expecting that parent will have some unnamed target **`ui-view=""`**